# JPA: Fetch data from DB instead of Persistance Context

Tags: java, jpa

I have a simple User Account application in which the user is able to change his details.

**Updating the Database**

*The Managed Bean's method which takes the form parameters and calls the Service method:*

```
public String changeDetails(){
    Date date = DateUtil.getDate(birthDate);
    Integer id = getAuthUser().getId();
    UserDetail newDetails = new UserDetail(id, occupation, date, originCity, residenceCity, description);

    EntityTransaction transaction = getTransaction();
    userService.updateDetail(newDetails);
    transaction.commit();

    return null;
}
```

*The Service Method:*

```
public boolean updateDetail(UserDetail newDetails) {
    boolean ok = true;
    if (newDetails != null) {
        UserDetail user = readDetail(newDetails.getId());

        user.setOccupation(newDetails.getOccupation());
        user.setOriginCity(newDetails.getOriginCity());
        user.setResidenceCity(newDetails.getResidenceCity());
        user.setBirth(newDetails.getBirth());
        user.setDescription(newDetails.getDescription());
    }
    return ok;
}
```

**Fetching data from DB**

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    userService = new UserService();
    sessionController.setAuthUser(userService.read(getAuthUser().getId()));
    originCity = getAuthUser().getUserDetail().getOriginCity();
    residenceCity = getAuthUser().getUserDetail().getResidenceCity();
    occupation = getAuthUser().getUserDetail().getOccupation();
    birthDate = DateUtil.getStringDate(getAuthUser().getUserDetail().getBirth());
    description = getAuthUser().getUserDetail().getDescription();
}
```

The problem is that the behavior of this code is different. Sometimes I obtain the desired result: once I submit the new details and call the `@PostConstruct init ()` the new details are printed. Some other times the old details are printed even though the DB entry is updated.

*Conclusion:* Sometimes the JPA brings me different result from what is in the DB. I guess that this results consist of data from the Persistance Context, data which isn't updated. Is there a way in which I can be sure that the JPA always brings the data directly from the DB? Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JPA 2 then `@Cacheable(false)` on your entity definition should make it read from the DB every time.

Answer (score 1):

You mean is there a way to turn the cache off  or empty it before an operation ?

```
emf.getCache().evictAll();
```

Comment: Thank you! But is it a good practice? I imagine that this Cache has its own role. Is it a good idea to exclude it or am I using JPA in a wrong way?